# Freehub is making loud noises and is randomly engaging/binding

Tags: noise, freehub

My freewheel recently started making some faint weird noises. I didn't pay much attention because everything was working fine. But as time went on, it started getting worse and worse. The noise was getting noticably louder and the freehub had started randomly engaging and trying to spin the chain while i was not pedaling and simply coasting.
**Here is a video of my bike showing the issue You can clearly hear the noises:**

I got this wheel brand new 4-5 months ago and i haven't really put it under abuse.

Is it possible to repair it by myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pawl/Ratchet mechanism is damaged. Take it back and get the wheel replaced, you generally have a year warranty.

Depending on the brand of hub, it might or might not be easy to take the freehub off and inspect the mechanism but given it's so young, it shouldn't be your problem, the shop should (in many places by law) repair or replace at no cost to you. Under 6 months in the UK, you can declare it's not fit for purpose and have an exchange; over 6 months, the manufacturer decides whether replacement or repair is better. The mechanism could be considered a wear part and you might have abused it but as so few wheels fail this way after such a short time, your case is strong.